# Xamarin: "Adding assembly reference recursively" message in out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, in my out/exit log of Visual Studio 2019 I see this messages:

```
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Essentials, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Core, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, recursively...
  Adding assembly reference for Xamarin.Forms.Platform, recursively...
```

What it means and how can I resolve it? Optimizing it can speed up the build and compile time of my project?

Comment: "Uncheck `Use rapid deployment` in the Android option tab of Android project"?

Comment: @Shaw I unchecked and still appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the Output window for the Debug selection of your visual studio, here you can select which types of messages to see.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Jessie, this message that is appearing to me is not on Debug output, it's from Compile output, it appears when I run my app and it is building. In the Output compile it doesn't have this boxes to unselect, just go until "Go to Previous Location".

Comment: The question is: What can I do in my code to Visual Studio doesn't have the need to add assemblies? Instead, I add it, the message doesn't appear and, like my question, if it can speed up the compile time.

Comment: `In the Output compile it doesn't have this boxes to unselect, just go until "Go to Previous Location"` What do you mean by words `Go to Previous Location` ? Where is the `Go to Previous Location` ?

Comment: See the image above, it's "Show output from Debug". The messages shown in "Show output from Compile" and doesn't have this boxes to unmark as your image shows.

Comment: Yes,  it is just the case as you said. In fac this type of log is a very common log and has little effect on the program.